# Back Button doesn't give me updated page

Tags: bug, firefox, back-button

Here's the scenario:

- I'll linger on a page for a short while, and upvotes, close-votes comments, edits, and other content will come in, and the page will update itself
- I click on some link to documentation or something
- I click the back button.

After I click the back button, all of the upvotes, comments, close votes, etc, that occurred while I was on the page, are not reflected in the page until I refresh.

This is sometimes disorienting.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It may be caching, but it's also newish behavior: I only started seeing this in the last few months.

Comment: This is known behavior for all web applications that leverage lots of ajax calls to update the page.  Either SE can invest TONS of time fixing something that everybody knows about and doesn't really care too much about, or browser manufacturers can update their cached page whenever the page's DOM is updated (or during certain intervals).  Nobody's blinking.

Comment: @Won't I don't think it would take "TONS" of time to just reload the page after someone hits "back"

Comment: Reload a page when you hit back?  Something tells me that's not a good idea...